# Find the dimension of the range of $T$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the dimension of the range of $T$ if $T$ is a transformation which satsifies the following:

Let A be a $3\times 4$ matrix which is row-equivalent to
[[1 2 0 3],[0 0 5 6],[0 0 0 0]], and let $T :\mathbb{R}^{3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{7}$ be a linear transformation such that $T(\mathbf x) = \mathbf 0$ if and only if $\mathbf x = A \mathbf y$ for some $\mathbf y \in \mathbb{R}^{4}$.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From rank–nullity theorem, we have
$$\dim\operatorname{Im}T = \dim\mathbb R^7 - \dim\ker T = 7 - \dim\ker T.$$

Since $A$ has two pivots, we have $\dim\operatorname{Im}A = 2.$

Finally, given that $Tx = 0$ iff $x = Ay$ for some $y\in\mathbb R^4$, then $\ker T = \operatorname{Im} A$ and from this $\dim\operatorname{Im}T = 5$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $A$ has a range with dimension $2$.  Conclude that the dimension of the kernel (nullspace) of the transformation $T$ is $2$.  Now that we know the dimension of the kernel of $T$, we can deduce the dimension of its range.